# What use does a player have for a DCI number?

Tags: dnd-adventurers-league, wizards-of-the-coast

Some friends talked me into creating a DCI number for an [AL session](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65676/what-is-dd-adventurers-league-and-how-does-it-work) (turns out I already had one, but that's another story). Anyway, I logged in to https://accounts.wizards.com and the things I see that I'm able to do from there are:

- View/print/email a pretty image with my DCI written down.
- Update my info / Change my password.

And that's it. (*ok, almost: there's a link to some Magic stuff, some DDI stuff, and some "Community" stuff I can't figure out*).

I get it, [AL seems like a good idea](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65679/4462), but I'm not sure I need a DCI for that. Sure, our [DM/organizer might get *swag/loot*](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/2eedgp/why_do_you_need_a_dci_for_adventure_leagues/) for it, and that's ok.

I guess I was expecting at least a simple table with my PC listed and the XP earned per session; as reported by the DM. Or maybe our DM didn't report anything?

**Is there something (RPG-related) that I (player) can do with my DCI?**

(*other than writing it down in my charsheet*)

Or is that all there is to it?

Comment: DCI number is more useful to Magic: the Gathering players as it helps them to see their Elo score online. I imagine the answer to your question has more to do with consistency of process than with helping D&D players specifically.

Comment: @acbabis The thing is, players in Adventurer's League are _encouraged_ to register a DCI. Since I don't play _Magic_, I was wondering if there was something interesting for role-players.

Comment: I understand. My point is that there probably isn't much reason for it.

Comment: @acbabis Minor nitpick: WOTC doesn't track ELO ratings for Magic players any more. You can look up your sanctioned match history and track your "planeswalker points" with a DCI number, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stores and some conventions use the DCI# to track player attendance. Stores can report it to increase their WPN (Wizards Play Network) level. Some conventions use it to track player attendance as well, but it's not necessary.

Ultimately there's no direct benefit for a player to have one, other than to help their local store with their WPN level.

Comment: Is there anything the store can gain from a higher WPN?

Comment: @Patrice See http://wpn.wizards.com/en/join-wpn for the benefits of the store levels. A lot of them relate to Magic events and products, but they may in turn bring more business into the store which can make it better for D&D play as well.