# Do AL reward points have any real-world value?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

If you play AL at a store or several stores, you might get a lot of points to help out your character and also some **reward points** for the store. Are the reward points worth anything to the players? For example, are points good toward discounts, buying other D&D products, maybe a thing like a keychain?

Comment: To be clear: are you talking about WPN rewards, not something that's being given to you, the player?

Answer (score 8):

There are no tangible rewards for Adventurers League play - just character advancement. It is possible that some specific venues may hand out awards, but they are not an implicit or inherent part of the Adventurers League format.

Stores that log games via the [Wizards Play Network](https://wpn.wizards.com/) derive benefit from it, but it is mostly focused on Magic: The Gathering. As [Raddu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2877/raddu), D&D Adventurers League Community Manager at the time, indicates [in an answer to related question regarding DCI numbers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99582/22138), there's no material benefit to a D&D player for WPN logging.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself. :-)