# What is the time frame?

Tags: forgotten-realms

I played last year at GenCon 2017. Still have my sheets and magic item. I was only third level. Can I use that same info to sign up again and finally get a DCI #? I ask because I would like to play a game or two.

Comment: Can you add a little more context? Is this an organized game like Adventurer's League, with official characters and requirements? Or does the con just have some DMs running their own games? And what do you mean with DCI #?

Comment: Check out these related questions: [What is D&D Adventurers League and How Does It Work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65676/what-is-dd-adventurers-league-and-how-does-it-work) and [What use does a player have for a DCI number?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99579/what-use-does-a-player-have-for-a-dci-number). CC: @Erik.